# What would P=NP tell us for a proof?

Tags: algorithm, proof, np

An exercise I've been working on is "Prove that there is no efficient 5/4-approximation toChromaticNumber unless P=NP.

My question is what would P=NP tell us? Let's say we "Suppose P=NP" in our proof. Does that mean that there is a 1-approximation algorithm? Or that the polynomial-time verifier is the same as the algorithm itself? A little confused here, any responses are appreciated!

Comment: Imagine that I give you a proof that if you had an algorithm giving a 5/4-approximation of ChromaticNumber in polynomial time, then you could use it to write an algorithm to solve a known NP-hard problem in polynomial time. Then effectively, my proof is saying "either P=NP, or there is no polynomial 5/4-approximation to ChromaticNumber".

Comment: PS: For other P=NP questions in the future, I recommend asking the question at https://cs.stackexchange.com rather than on stackoverflow. It's a stackexchange specifically for computer science, and you're more likely to get insightful answers there.

Comment: The problem is to prove that finding a 5/4 approximation to chromatic number is NP-hard, by reducing a known NP-hard problem to that.